# How can i get PHP to ignore extension like how PHPUnit does in Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: php, command-prompt

On Windows i have the following script in a file called TrelloInt.main.php

```
<?php

    $importData = file_get_contents("TrelloData\TrelloJsonExport.txt");
    $json = json_decode($importData);
    var_dump($json);

?>
```

all the file does is `var_dump` the decoded json object to the screen.

when i open up Command Prompt i use the following script in a batch file

```
d:
cd "_Work\Automation\Selenium\_Selenium Server"

start call selenium
SET PATH=%PATH%;D:\_Work\Automation\Selenium\_php5.6.14;
cd ../
cls
```

selenium is a call to a batch file to start up selenium server but for this isn't important, the important part is `SET PATH=%PATH%;D:\_Work\Automation\Selenium\_php5.6.14;` which i use so i can just use `php` or `phpunit` in Command Prompt from any folder

inside my php folder i have a phpunit.cmd file with the following line

```
@php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %*
```

now from Command Prompt if i call `php TrelloInt.main.php` i get my var_dump, likewise if i used `phpunit TrelloInt.main.php` with the exception it complains that there is no TrelloInt.main class (expected)

however i can call my php file with `phpunit trelloint.main` and it'll work fine but when i call my file with `php trelloint.main` it says it can't open but it'll work just fine when i add .php at the end.

Is there a way for me to get php to ignore the extension at the end like how PHPUnit does in Windows Command Prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Windows' command prompt, and nothing to do with ignoring extensions.

The PHP interpreter and PHPUnit simply expect different arguments:

- [`php` expects a *file* as its argument](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php). It happily accepts something like `trelloint.main.php`.
- [`phpunit` expects a *class* as its argument](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php), and assumes that classes exist in files named like the classes themselves. So when given argument `foo` it looks for it in `foo.php`.

As far as I know there is no way to invoke PHP code by class using the `php` binary, and a look at [its options](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) doesn't reveal any way to do this.